# php to create record in Knack database doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, database, api

well, tried this once before but didn't get any responses.  made a little progress though, so thought i'd try again.  i can successfully create a record in a Knack database vie their api using javascript.  trying to come up with php code instead of javascript.  not expecting total familiarity with Knack databases, although that would be nice, but just hoping some php monster might look at this code and see something dreadfully wrong.  or something.

anyway, below is the javascript that works, followed by a typical attempt at a php version that just results in an Internal Server Error.  thanks in advance for any assistance.

## working javascript: creates record in database

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://#############.com/v1/pages/some_scene/views/some_view/records",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "X-Knack-Application-Id": "########################",
    "X-Knack-REST-API-Key": "########-####-####-####-############",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",  
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": '{ "some_field": "some data" }'
}


$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

## php version: results in Internal Server Error

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://#############.com/v1/pages/scene_23/views/view_36/records');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  'X-Knack-REST-API-Key' => '########-####-####-####-############',
  'X-Knack-Application-Id' => '########################'
));

$request->setBody('{
    "some_field": "some data"
  }');

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

funny addendum.  turns out i get an Internal Server Error just trying to execute this line:

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
```

i can run php code from this server so...  i'm not sure what this is about.  and i'm trying to run without pecl or curl if i can.  do i need something like that for http requests?

Comment: Check your servers error log to see the actual error message.

Comment: thanks magnus.  interesting.  haha and makes more sense with my addendum.  i had been running this on a work server that i don't really have totall access to.  so i ran it on my own (where yes, i can run php) and that looks terrible.  don't seem to be logging anything, but for an error i'm getting: Class 'HttpRequest' not found.  is there any way to do with with straight php, or do i need to install pecl or curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the server's configuration (particularly [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)) you might be able to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to make this request without installing curl (tested with php 5.6):

```
$request_url = 'https://#############.com/v1/pages/scene_23/views/view_36/records';

$request_body = '{"some_field":"some data"}';

$request_context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => [
            'X-Knack-Application-Id: ########################',
            'X-Knack-REST-API-Key: ########-####-####-####-############',
            'Content-Type: application/json',  
        ],
        'content' => $request_body,
        'ignore_errors' => true, // return error message, if any, in response_body
    ],
]);

$response_body = file_get_contents($request_url, false, $request_context);

var_dump($response_body);
```

Comment: astrangeloop!  you're like a genius!!!  worked exactly as you wrote it. 
 hahaha well ok, i guess you just got your php stuff down, but excellent.  i'm a good flash guy, pretty good javascript guy, but my php...  ok, stinks.  these days i do a lot of hunting through stuff i don't know anything about.  just haven't been having a lot of luck with this one for a while, but cool, and i don't understand it yet :)  but thanks.  guess i better get studyin'.  echo 'hello world';...  wait, that already makes me laugh.  i had to look up var_dump().